# Looking for a movie in which vampires died from being thrown into the ocean

Tags: story-identification, vampire

I remember watching a movie when I was a child (perhaps something made only for TV, I don't recall much from that), in which there were vampires that would die from being thrown into the sea. The reason given in-universe was that [vampires had no minerals in their blood and thus died from hypertension because of the salt in the water](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ArtisticLicenseBiology).

I honestly don't recall much from the story except for that. The movie was in color, and I watched it something like 15 years ago (yet with all the rebroadcastings, doesn't mean much). It was in French, but yet again, the primary language may have been English.

Does it ring a bell for anyone else? Has this particular vampire biology been used in several works?

Comment: And you were a child....when? Color? B&W? English? Any other details you can remember?

Comment: Don't know if this helps any but _[Daze and Knights: the Truth Behind Vampires and Zombies](https://books.google.co.nz/books?id=4-PdAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA19&lpg=PA19&dq=vampire+death+by+salt&source=bl&ots=CrCS4a4WvU&sig=Xh2ikNPEqmJT6FJsPYCHb3-7c1o&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi3l4-I283XAhVGUZQKHVflCVc4ChDoAQg4MAQ#v=onepage&q=vampire%20death%20by%20salt&f=false)_ is one of the only works I know of that has a science-y explanation of water poisoning Vampires.

Comment: Not the right thing, because not vampires, but this reminds me a little of the climax of *Alien Nation* -- salt water was like battery acid to the titular aliens.

Comment: Probably more likely to cause [crenation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crenation) of the red blood cells rather than high blood pressure.

Comment: In *Alien Nation* (1988 film; 1989 TV series), the alien Newcomers received severe chemical burns from exposure to salt water.  The film and series also dealt with monstrous transformed versions of the standard Newcomers.

Comment: However, scientifically, pure water would cause hypertension/edema in creatures with very concentrated blood minerals; if their blood had very low salinity, salt water would draw the water out of their tissues and cause dehydration (as, indeed, it will with us on long enough exposure).

Comment: @JohnP added the very few details I remember. It came back listening to a podcast in which the host said something about throwing vampires in the ocean to kill them thanks to hypertension... I'm afraid I won't find much more. And apparently no one else remembers this.

Comment: Robert R. McCammon's "They Thirst" is a novel where salt water kills vampires, at the end there is a flood in LA to kill them. I don't think it has ever been adapted for film but it is possible.